# How to capture thumbnail for video while uploading it in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video-thumbnails

I want to know how to capture thumbnail for video while uploading it in ASP.NET ?

Comment: Please give some more detail on what you're trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151348/create-thumbnail-from-video-in-asp-net)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all, you will also need to convert it to MP4 which will work on everywhere. For that you can use ffmpeg tool,

To Create Thumbnail,

```
//Create Thumbs
string thumbpath, thumbname;
string thumbargs;
string thumbre;
thumbpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Video\\Thumb\\";
thumbname = thumbpath + withoutext + "%d" + ".jpg";
thumbargs = "-i " + inputfile + " -vframes 1 -ss 00:00:07 -s 150x150 " + thumbname;
Process thumbproc = new Process();
thumbproc = new Process();
thumbproc.StartInfo.FileName = spath + "\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe";
thumbproc.StartInfo.Arguments = thumbargs;
thumbproc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
thumbproc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
thumbproc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
try
{
thumbproc.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
thumbproc.WaitForExit();
thumbproc.Close();
```

However, for more details about the code, see this link.

http://ramcrishna.blogspot.com/2008/09/playing-videos-like-youtube-and.html

And you will need to change paths according to your web application's path.